# Не получается вставлять переменные в БД

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
  //Подключение к БД

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Подключение не удалось: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }//Если подключеник не удалось
  $hash = str_rand(); //Случайная строка
  $usern = $_POST["name"]; //Имя пользователя
  $passn = $_POST["pass"]; //Пароль пользователя
  $emailn = $_POST["email"]; //Email пользователя
 if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserAgree (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
   echo "1";
   if(!$stmt){
     echo "Ошибка";
     exit();
   }

  /* связываем параметры с метками */
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $usern);
  echo "2";

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $hash);
  echo "3";


  /* запускаем запрос */
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "4";

  if ($conn->execute() === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
      echo "Error: ". "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  echo "5";


  $stmt->close();
  echo "6";

  }
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (login, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    echo "7";

  /* связываем параметры с метками */
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $usern);
  echo "8";

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $passn);
  echo "9";

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $emailn);
  echo "10";

  /* запускаем запрос */
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "11";

  if ($conn->execute() === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  echo "12";


  $stmt->close();
  echo "13";


  }
  $conn->close();
```

Вывод: 1234

Comment: `$conn->execute()` что это такое?

Comment: Нет времени объяснять, выполняй всё.